PhotosPicker freezes at loading stage (SwiftUI)
The issue is - I am trying to load video from the gallery to my app but I can not succeed. Here are relevant pieces of code
This is my Transferable struct
struct Movie: Transferable {
    let url: URL

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { movie in
            SentTransferredFile(movie.url)
        } importing: { received in
            let copy = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "movie.mp4")

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copy.path()) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copy)
            }

            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: received.file, to: copy)
            return Self.init(url: copy)
        }
    }
}

This is my SwiftUI code
struct GalleryView: View {
    
    
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?

    ....

    // Somewhere in ZStack of GalleryView
    HStack {
                
        Spacer()
                 
        VStack {
                    
            Spacer()
                    
            PhotosPicker(
               selection: $selectedItem,
               matching: .videos)
            {
                Image("btn_plus")
            }
            .padding(.bottom, 16)
                    
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 16)
      }

      ..........

      .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newValue in
            Task {
                do {
                    print("loading!!!...")
                    
                    if let movie = try await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) {
                        print("loaded!!!...")
                    } else {
                        print("failed!!!...")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("failed with ex!!!...")
                }
            }
        }

So when I run the code, I see my button, I press it, Gallery opens up with videos only (as intented). Then I pick some video and I see this log
loading!!!...

And execution goes into loadTransferable and never comes back. I am pretty sure I made some newbie mistake because this is the first time I am attaching this functionality in SwiftUI. Could you please point me out what did I do wrong? Thank you!

There is a similar problem here. How about using a DataRepresentation instead?

Hello Sweeper! Thank you for your suggestion, I will definitely give it a shot.

I tried your code in my tests, and all works well for me.
On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4, tested on real ios 17 devices and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. I can show my test code if you are interested.

@workingdogsupportUkraine Hello! Thank you for the effort! Very interesting.. Could you please share it with me?

I have exactly the same setup as you do..

Hello @Sweeper! I am looking into DataRepresentation thing and I don't see how it is supposed to solve this issue. Could you please provide me some guidance on this? Thank you very much!

Upvoting because I have a similar (visual, ux) issue that has to do with Photopicker stalling for 200-1000ms. No idea why you got downvoted

Well, now it works. Why is that? No idea. The only assumption I have is that I added photoLibrary: .shared()), so PhotosPicker code looks like this:
PhotosPicker(
    selection: $viewModel.videoPicker.videoSelection,
    matching: .videos,
    photoLibrary: .shared())
    {
        Image("btn_plus")
    }
        .padding(.bottom, 16)

But when I removed photoLibrary: .shared() just to make sure if this is the reason, code also works... Maybe the first call with photoLibrary: .shared() engaged granting permissions to the app to view files in Gallery? I don't know... but there you go. I am not marking this post as an answer to my question, because it is clearly not.
UPDATE:
OMG, how inconsistent is PhotosPicker in SwiftUI, you guys have no idea. Code above no longer works - again. Sometimes it loads the video, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it looks like it depends on longevity or size of the video, but sometimes it can not load 5 second video, but can load 10 minutes video.
Finally I fixed it by implementing UIKit solution with PHPickerViewController. It is very stable, and uploads absolutely any video I pick from the Gallery and does it consistently. Feel free to use it:
//
//  PickVideoFromGalleryView.swift
//  spintip-iOS-app
//
//  Created by Yevhen Alieksieiev on 14.05.2024.
//

import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI
import AVKit
import Combine

final class PickVideoFromGalleryCoordinator: NSObject {
    var parent: PickVideoFromGalleryView
 
    init(_ parent: PickVideoFromGalleryView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

extension PickVideoFromGalleryCoordinator: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        
        guard let pickedSelection = results.first else {
            self.parent.errorMsg = "No video was selected"
            return
        }
        
        let itemProvider = pickedSelection.itemProvider
        
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
            let progress = itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { [weak self] url, error in
                do {
                    guard let url = url, error == nil else {
                        throw error ?? NSError(domain: NSFileProviderErrorDomain, code: -1, userInfo: nil)
                    }
                    let localURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
                    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: localURL)
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: localURL)
                    
                    self?.parent.videoUrl = IdentifiableURL(url: localURL)
                    

                } catch let catchedError {
                    
                    self?.parent.errorMsg = catchedError.localizedDescription
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.parent.errorMsg = "You can process videos only"
        }
    }
}

struct PickVideoFromGalleryView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = PHPickerViewController
    
    @Binding var videoUrl: IdentifiableURL?
    @Binding var errorMsg: String?
    
    public init(videoUrl: Binding<IdentifiableURL?>, errorMsg: Binding<String?>) {
        _videoUrl = videoUrl
        _errorMsg = errorMsg
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewControllerType {
        
        var configuration = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
        
        // Set the filter type according to the user’s selection.
        configuration.filter = PHPickerFilter.videos
        // Set the mode to avoid transcoding, if possible, if your app supports arbitrary image/video encodings.
        configuration.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current
        // Set the selection behavior to respect the user’s selection order.
        configuration.selection = .ordered
        // Set the selection limit to enable multiselection.
        configuration.selectionLimit = 1
        
        let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return picker
    }
    
    // In our case we do not need to update our `AVPlayerViewController` when AVPlayer changes
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    // Creates the coordinator that is used to handle and communicate changes in `AVPlayerViewController`
    func makeCoordinator() -> PickVideoFromGalleryCoordinator {
        PickVideoFromGalleryCoordinator(self)
    }
}


Here is my test code, to select a video using PhotosPicker and display it in a View.
struct Movie: Transferable {
    let url: URL
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { movie in
            SentTransferredFile(movie.url)
        } importing: { received in
            
            print("----> in Movie received: \(received.file)")
            
            let copy = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "movie.mp4")
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copy.path()) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copy)
            }
            
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: received.file, to: copy)
            return Self.init(url: copy)
        }
    }
}

struct GalleryView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var player = AVPlayer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .frame(width: 345, height: 345)
                .padding(20)
            
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedItem, matching: .videos) {
                Image(systemName: "video.circle").resizable()
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) {
            Task {
                do {
                    if let movie = try await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) {
                        print("----> in GalleryView movie: \(movie.url)")
                        player = AVPlayer(url: movie.url)
                    } else {
                        print("----> GalleryView failed...")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("----> GalleryView error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GalleryView()
    }
}

